# Change attribute type

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to change the attribute `type` of an element? Scrathing my head about this - all I can find is how to change the `value` of an attribute.

I want to change `href` to `src` on the element above. I have a script that change the element type to an iframe for mobiles, and I need the attribute to be a src type for it to work.

```
<a class="colorbox cboxElement" href="http://example.com">Diablo</a>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: src won't work on an anchor

Comment: do you want to change id dynamically ?

Comment: Why do you need to add a non-valid attribute to an anchor element, what problem do you think this solves?

Comment: Im changing the A element to an iframe type for mobile use, and I need the src atttribute for it to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "iframe type"? If you're turning an anchor into an iframe you'll need to replace the elemen, changing its attributes won't work.

Comment: It works for me, with the below answer.

Comment: It takes you to `example.com` when you click it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method to remove an attribute and [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to set an attribute.

```js
$('.colorbox').attr('src', function() {
  return $(this).attr('href');
}).removeAttr('href');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="colorbox cboxElement" href="http://example.com">Diablo</a>
```

---

With pure Javascript use [`Element#setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method to set attribute where you can get attribute value using [`Element#getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method and remove an attribute using [`Element#removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) method.

```js
var ele = document.querySelector('.colorbox');
ele.setAttribute('src', ele.getAttribute('href'));
ele.removeAttribute('href');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="colorbox cboxElement" href="http://example.com">Diablo</a>
```

**FYI :** The jQuery method would work for multiple elements, in Javascript you need to iterate over the element collection to update multiple.

For eg:

```
// for older browser use [].slice.call(....).forEach
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.colorbox')).forEach(function(ele){
 // do the rest here
})
```

Comment: Note that the jQuery and the plain JS solutions are not equivalent, because the jQuery version is able to change the attribute for multiple elements (because it loops behind the scenes).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can change any attribute.

Use:

```
element.setAttribute(attribute_name, attribute_value)
```

and to get the value of attribute use

```
element.getAttribute(attribute_name)
```

Note that not every attribute is going to have an effect on element.
For example, setting **type** attribute on **input** element is going to create input of given type, but setting it on **span** does nothing.

If You want to hold some data information in attributes, I would recommend to use [dataset API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use just javascript, you could get the attribute using `getAttribute`,  set the new attribute using `setAttribute`, and remove the old attribute using `removeAttribute`.

```js
var tag = document.getElementsByClassName('cboxElement')[0];
tag.setAttribute('src', tag.getAttribute('href'));
tag.removeAttribute('href');
```

```html
<a class="colorbox cboxElement" href="http://example.com">Diablo</a>
```